# apex which populates Account Record Type info into "MC Commercial Setup" field for all existing customers. This job will be run only once

Tags: apex, batch

For Account, we have some record types defined like 'small organisation', 'large organisation', 'business' etc. There are 2 millions records.

Requirement: I need to update custom field MC_Commercial_Setup__c with the record type name only if record type name (RecordType.name) is 'small organisation' or 'large organisation'.

I need to run the job only once then all existing records needs to update with the record type name.

I tried to accomplish this task with the code below but it's not working:

```
global class BatchUpdateAccount implements Database.Batchable { 
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) { 
        String query= 'select Id, RecordType.Name, MC_Commercial_Setup__c from Account '; 
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query); 
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> acc){
        Map<Id,Account> accMap = new Map<Id,Account>(acc);
        for(Account ac: acc){
            if( acnt.RecordType.Name='Large Organisation' || acnt.RecordType.Name='SME/SOHO Organisation'){
            ac.MC_Commercial_Setup__c = accMap.get(ac.id).RecordType.Name;
            system.debug(ac);
            }
        }
        update acc;
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {

    }
}
```

---

Getting Errors for below code like :

> "variable does not exist acnt.RecordType" and
>
> "Expression cannot be assigned"

at 11th line

`( if( acnt.RecordType.Name='Large Organisation' || acnt.RecordType.Name='SME/SOHO Organisation'){ )`

but MC_Commercial_Setup__c field in Account not updating with the record type value when run the job

```
global class BatchUpdateAccount implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
     global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        String query= 'select Id, RecordType.Name, MC_Commercial_Setup__c from Account ';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query); 
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> acc){
        Map<Id,Account> accMap = new Map<Id,Account>(acc);
        for(Account ac: acc){
            if( acnt.RecordType.Name='Large Organisation' || acnt.RecordType.Name='SME/SOHO Organisation'){
            ac.MC_Commercial_Setup__c = accMap.get(ac.id).RecordType.Name;
            system.debug(ac);
            }
        }
        update acc;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {}}
```

Code on Anonymous window:

```
BatchUpdateAccount xyz=new BatchUpdateAccount();
Database.executeBatch(xyz);
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. Can you provide some more details on ``not working``? Do you receive an error in ``Apex Jobs``, records are no updated?

Comment: No errors. MC_Commercial_Setup__c  field in Account not updating with the record type value when i run the job

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide that information there. Also - add a code with invoking the batch class as well.

Comment: Let's be clear here. There are indeed errors, and they are _compile-time_ errors. This job cannot be run at all.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have assignment:

```
acnt.RecordType.Name = 'Large Organisation' || acnt.RecordType.Name = 'SME/SOHO Organisation'
```

instead of comparison:

```
ac.RecordType.Name == 'Large Organisation' || ac.RecordType.Name == 'SME/SOHO Organisation'
```

That is the error you're getting:

> "Expression cannot be assigned"

The second error happens because you ask for **acnt** instead of **ac** that is used in for-loop.

**P.S.:** I also do not really understand for which purpose you are using **accMap**, in if-clause you can just use:

```
ac.MC_Commercial_Setup__c = ac.RecordType.Name;
```

Comment: Super .It is working fine now.Thank you

Comment: Is it work for 2M records?

Comment: @KavyaKM It is batch, o yes, execute relatable scope size, do not forget that you can set your update in trigger up to 150 times (DML limit per transaction is 150)